# How to call a function to print a 2D const char* array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I would like to be able to call a function with a 2D array named using const char*. In my program, I open up a CSV input, read the number of lines, create a 2D array of the appropriate size (copy over the data from the file-this step is not in the code for the sake of the question) and then want to print it (not in the main function though, to cut down on number of lines).

For this example we can ignore the CSV component so I've added a sample array just to try it out.

I know I'm getting lost in the pointers somewhere in the hand-off of the array between main() and show() since I'm getting the error "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector." I just don't know how to fix it. Any pointers on how to remedy this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define col 4

void show(const char* A){
    int i, j;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            if(A[i][j])
                printf("%s\t", A[i][j]);
            else
                printf("%s\t", "NULL");
        }    
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main () {
    FILE* t1count = fopen("input/t1_input.csv", "r");
    t1row = countlines(t1count); // Where countlines is another function I have written but not relevant in this case

    const char *strings[t1row][col]; //For this example we can use: = {{"4001","CA52","C14M731345","5"},{"4010","CA52","C14M731559","5"},{"4101","CA52","C14M731559","5"},{"4029","CA72","B15M731038","9"}};

    show(strings);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with `const char *`? `const char *strings[][]` is not the same thing as `const char *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is type mismatch between your function parameter `void show(const char* A)` and the argument you are passing while calling `show(strings);`

change your function prototype to

```
void show(const char* A[][col])
```